# On neo4j I have this kind of error : expected Path but was Collection<Path>?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently using neo4j. I am trying to study the graph-databases trough neo4j. For my study I need to perform some queries. And I am having a problem with this one :

```
Match path = (a:Node)-[:Rel1|Rel2*7..8]-(b:Node), (c:Node)

Where (a:Node)-[:Rel1|Rel2*7..8]-(b:Node) and (a:Node)-[:Rel1|Rel2*7..8]-(c:Node) and (b:Node)-[:Rel1|Rel2*7..8]-(c:Node)

With a as aa, b as bb, c as cc, (a:Node)-[:Rel1|Rel2*7..8]-(b:Node) as path1,
(a:Node)-[:Rel1|Rel2*7..8]-(c:Node) as path2, (c:Node)-[:Rel1|Rel2*7..8]-(b:Node) as path3

Limit 1

With a as aa, b as bb, c as cc,
path1 as path1, path2 as path2, path3 as path3, Extract(rel in relationships(path1) | rel.id) as relIDs1, Extract(rel in relationships(path2) | rel.id) as relIDs2, Extract(rel in relationships(path3) | rel.id) as relIDs3

Return path1, path2, path3
```

I am having a problem with the second with, neo4j do return a single path (I only need 1 path "Limit 1") when I comment this line, but when I am trying to do that expected Path but was Collection on the extract. How could I deal with the problem, I tried to look at the documentation bu I have no idea.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j's behavior is to return data as Collection, even if there is only one item. It would be much more confusing if the return type was inconsistent, so this really is a good thing. Just grab the 1st element from the collection, store that in you `Path` type variable, and go on you way.